# 16×2 LCD built-in specifications

Tags: lcd

Do we need to manually force cursor to move rightwards in 16×2 LCD to display a string?  How is it done with intel 8051?

Comment: Welcome! Your description is far from complete, using 16x2 LCD description is like saying I drive a 4x4 how fast will it go? Tell us what you are driving the LCD with, and what processor. Most of the functions you need are in the various libraries and they are not all the same.

Comment: I thought the thing in question is a built-in feature and is applicable to all 16×2 LCDs

Comment: how is intel 8051 relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You should give more details on your LCD and a link to a spec. Here is a link to a very common 16x2 LCD, probably the one that you are using. https://github.com/kierdavis/lcd1602/blob/master/datasheets/eone-1602a1.pdf  They are sold under many different brand names.

You are probably using it in 8-bit parallel mode, it is fairly straightforward to use in this mode. It is often sold with an add-on serial to 4-bit parallel interface, less wires but the S/W is more complicated (you don't seem to have this option).

0x38 sets the function to 8 bit bus, 2 line display.

0x0F sets the display on, cursor on.

0x01 clears the display, this is a slow function, be sure to allow plenty of time before the next command.

0x06 sets the cursor mode, increment (move right) on char write, shift (scroll) off.

0x80 sets the cursor position.

Comment: Oh. The reference material I used just mentioned that 0x06 will "increment the cursor" and I interpreted it as a standalone command that will force the cursor to move rightwards whether or not a character is displayed. Now I think I was wrong and my reference material isn't proper.

Comment: By the way,can somebody suggest some good reference materials or something like a handbook detailing these kind of things?

Comment: @AlbinSPhilip It is called the datasheet for your LCD module, or failing that, the datasheet for the controller chip that is on your LCD module.

Comment: The datasheet that I linked is better than most datasheets for cheap hobby oriented modules. 90% of the users are probably using a pre-existing driver for one of the popular MCUs.

Comment: Isn't there a set of standards for manufacturing such things?

Comment: @Philip No, every LCD controller IC manufacturer can make any custom command set they feel like. There is no standard. However, most LCD controller ICs for 16x2 LCDs tend to be mostly Hitachi HD44780 clones and compatibles so they usually are interchangeable. I guess that can be called a de facto standard as it has been used since 1983 or so.

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't need to manually set cursor position, but you can if you want to. There is a "Set Cursor Position" command.

Comment: I saw somewhere that aforementioned LCD can be initialized py passing commands 0x38,0x0F,0x01,0x06,0x80. I didn't understand the logic behind sending 0x06 and then 0x80.Can somebody explain this?.I don't know whether the whole thing I said is correct or wrong as I don't have any trustworthy sources to cite.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use. It's automatically incremented. [Click here to link](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf)
Please read page number 9 about the Address Counter .

**"After writing into (reading from) DDRAM or CGRAM, the AC is automatically incremented by 1 (decremented by 1)."**

There are two registers, an instruction register (IR) and a data register (DR).

In this case you have to set IR to b"1000_0000" (to use DDRAM) before you can set DR.

Comment: If that is the case,do I need to pass 0x06 command to the LCD before passing a string to be displayed?

Comment: @Philip There are two registers, an instruction register (IR) and a data register (DR).
You have to write the IR, then you can continue use DR without using IR.

Comment: @Philip It's 0x80 for DDRAM. CGRAM is probably another one which you can see from the datasheet. I haven't used CGRAM yet so I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be setting it up as I2C which the 8051 will support. Here is a link to how to do that: https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/microcontrollers/8051/8051-i2c-interfacing-tutorial-eeprom/ Libraries are available on Github: One of those will make your work much easier. With the I2C interface you can add a lot of I/O memory devices etc.

Comment: What does I2C has to do with the LCD or what commands to send to it, even if it would be over an I2C IO expander?